# rsync exclude a single file from the root folder

Tags: command-line, rsync

I want to rsync from a folder, which contanins **index.php** (which need to be excluded), and many other directories contains index.php too. i created an exclude file and added index.php there. but all the index.php files were gone. Is there any proper method to avoid the only file from syncing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

rsync uses directories relative to the root rsync folder.  You should be able to achieve this using something like

```
rsync -aAX ./ ../target --exclude=/index.php
```

The "`/`" will indicate the root directory.

Comment: I tried that too (./index.php) but, unfortunately, excluded all index.php

Comment: @RajeshRajendran I have updated my answer, this worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't work at all in my version of rsync.

Comment: apparently this only works if the source directory has a trailing '/'. i couldn't find a reference to this in the docs anywhere, i'm guessing it must be a bug.

Comment: @Spongman if `src` does not have trailing `/`, the root is `src`. E.i.:
`rsync --exclude='/a/index.php' a b`

Answer (score 11):

The `--exclude` filter works like this:

- If the pattern does not start with a slash, then it matches at the end of the path, anywhere in the tree.

  `--exclude myfile.txt` matches any file called `myfile.txt` in *any* directory.

  `--exclude logs/myfile.txt` matches `myfile.txt` inside *any* directory called `logs`.
- If the pattern begins with a slash, it is anchored to *the root of the transferred files*.

  To determine what the root of the transferred files is, remove everything after the last slash in the *source* path.

  For example, in the following rsync command, the source path is `/srv/files/something` and so the root of the transfer is `/srv/files/`.

  ```
  rsync -a /srv/files/something host:/backup/files/
  ```

  So, to exclude source file `/srv/files/logs/myfile.txt` you would use `--exclude /logs/myfile.txt`, where that slash at the start of the exclude pattern refers to the root of the transfer, which is rooted at `/srv/files/` (on the source).

Comment: this is a really good explanation - I was unable to find this documented in my version of rsync man page.  is there are officially documented source that explains this?

Comment: It's explained under the subheadings "INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES" and "ANCHORING INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERNS" in the manpage (eg [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rsync.1.html#contenttoc16) or [here](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html)).